# Docker: Files from volume not updated in target

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm newbie in Docker and I have created an image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.12.0
LABEL version="1.0"
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I run the image and it works. But If I run the image mapping host directory with WORKDIR when I update index.js in host directory this updating is not propagated into WORKDIR.

I run the image with this command:

```
docker run --name basketmetrics -v /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics2:/usr/src/app -p 8080:8080 -d basketmetrics2/node-app:1.0
```

This is my host directory /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics2

[image]

And this is the target directory in the container /usr/src/app. If I inspect the container I can see that the host directory is mapped with the WORKDIR

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update I:**

I have stoped my container and modify the file index.js in my host directory. If I run again the image, then I can see the content updated!!!

Why my content is not updated on the fly?

Comment: "And this is the target directory in the container /usr/src/app." Is there something missing?

Comment: No, the directory in the container where is defined the WORKDIR is /usr/src/app

Comment: I meant below "This is my host directory /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics2", there is a screenshot, but after "And this is the target directory in the container /usr/src/app" there isn't really anything.

Comment: Ups, sorry!!! A little bit under you can see a screen cap from the mapping.

Comment: Your changes on the host should definitely be visible immediately inside the container. So you "entered" your container with `docker exec -it basketmetrics bash` and the files didn't change, when you changed them on the host?

Comment: I have changed my file in Visual Code but this change didn't propagate to the container. I have modified the message that I can see on the web page and this message is not updated in my browser. Then, I have stoped my container and run again. And now, I can see the web page updated.

Comment: The answer given below might be it, but I would really check with `docker exec -it basketmetrics bash` and `cat` / `vim` inside the container, to make sure, it's not your browser cache, which is fooling you.

Comment: Thank you @hjsimpson for your help!!! I have thinked in browser cache and I made sure that it was not the browser cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like known issue. [Link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793#issuecomment-135411504)

> If you are using some editor like vim, when you save the file it does
>   not save the file directly, rather it creates a new file and copies it
>   into place. This breaks the bind-mount, which is based on inode. Since
>   saving the file effectively changes the inode, changes will not
>   propagate into the container. When the container is restarted the new
>   inode. If you edit the file in place you should see changes propagate.
>
> **This is a known limitation of file-mounts and is not fixable.**

Further in comments you can find some workarounds for various editors. Check if any works

Comment: It seems that this is my problem, because when I stop and run again the container I can see the update. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Where your home directory lives? I have tested that it works on local disk bind mounts , and required a restart if the home directory is from NFS mount